# RUNTIME ERROR: Index out of range taking subset of theta

Tags: r, jags, rjags, r2jags, runjags

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
y   s
1   cat
0   cat
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
1   dog
1   cat
0   dog
0   dog
1   dog
0   dog
1   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
1   cat
1   dog
0   cat
1   dog
0   dog
1   dog
1   cat
1   dog
1   dog
1   dog
1   cat
1   cat
1   dog
1   dog
0   cat
1   dog
0   dog
0   cat
1   dog
1   dog
0   dog
1   dog
0   cat
1   dog
1   dog
1   cat
1   cat
1   dog
0   dog
1   cat
1   dog
0   dog
0   dog
1   dog
1   cat
1   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
1   cat
1   dog
1   dog
1   dog
1   cat
1   cat
1   dog
1   dog
0   cat
1   dog
0   dog
0   cat
1   dog
1   dog
0   dog
1   dog
0   cat
1   dog
1   dog
1   cat
1   cat
1   dog
0   dog
1   cat
1   dog
0   dog
0   dog
1   dog
1   cat
1   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
0   dog
1   cat
```

I am performing an MCMC algorithm using jags but I always get the error:

```
Error in jags.model("TEMPmodel.txt", data = dataList, inits = initsList, : RUNTIME ERROR: Compilation error on line 4. Index out of range taking subset of theta
```

This is the source file:

```
Ssubj-Mbernbeta.R 
# Accompanies the book:
#   Kruschke, J. K. (2014). Doing Bayesian Data Analysis: 
#   A Tutorial with R, JAGS, and Stan. 2nd Edition. Academic Press / Elsevier.
source("DBDA2E-utilities.R")
#===============================================================================

genMCMC = function( data , numSavedSteps=50000 , saveName=NULL ) { 
  require(rjags)
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # THE DATA.
  # N.B.: This function expects the data to be a data frame, 
  # with one component named y being a vector of integer 0,1 values,
  # and one component named s being a factor of subject identifiers.
  y = data$y
  s = as.numeric(data$s) # converts character to consecutive integer levels
  # Do some checking that data make sense:
  if ( any( y!=0 & y!=1 ) ) { stop("All y values must be 0 or 1.") }
  Ntotal = length(y)
  Nsubj = length(unique(s))
  # Specify the data in a list, for later shipment to JAGS:
  dataList = list(
    y = y ,
    s = s ,
    Ntotal = Ntotal ,
    Nsubj = Nsubj
  )
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # THE MODEL.
  modelString = "
  model {
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      y[i] ~ dbern( theta[s[i]] )
    }
    for ( sIdx in 1:Nsubj ) {
      theta[sIdx] ~ dbeta( 2 , 2 ) # N.B.: 2,2 prior; change as appropriate.
    }
  }
  "
  # close quote for modelString
  writeLines( modelString , con="TEMPmodel.txt" )
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # INTIALIZE THE CHAINS.
  # Initial values of MCMC chains based on data:
  # Option 1: Use single initial value for all chains:
  #  thetaInit = rep(0,Nsubj)
  #  for ( sIdx in 1:Nsubj ) { # for each subject
  #    includeRows = ( s == sIdx ) # identify rows of this subject
  #    yThisSubj = y[includeRows]  # extract data of this subject
  #    thetaInit[sIdx] = sum(yThisSubj)/length(yThisSubj) # proportion
  #  }
  #  initsList = list( theta=thetaInit )
  # Option 2: Use function that generates random values near MLE:
  initsList = function() {
    thetaInit = rep(0,Nsubj)
    for ( sIdx in 1:Nsubj ) { # for each subject
      includeRows = ( s == sIdx ) # identify rows of this subject
      yThisSubj = y[includeRows]  # extract data of this subject
      resampledY = sample( yThisSubj , replace=TRUE ) # resample
      thetaInit[sIdx] = sum(resampledY)/length(resampledY) 
    }
    thetaInit = 0.001+0.998*thetaInit # keep away from 0,1
    return( list( theta=thetaInit ) )
  }
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RUN THE CHAINS
  parameters = c( "theta")     # The parameters to be monitored
  adaptSteps = 500             # Number of steps to adapt the samplers
  burnInSteps = 500            # Number of steps to burn-in the chains
  nChains = 4                  # nChains should be 2 or more for diagnostics 
  thinSteps = 1
  nIter = ceiling( ( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains )
  # Create, initialize, and adapt the model:
  jagsModel = jags.model( "TEMPmodel.txt" , data=dataList , inits=initsList , 
                          n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )
  # Burn-in:
  cat( "Burning in the MCMC chain...\n" )
  update( jagsModel , n.iter=burnInSteps )
  # The saved MCMC chain:
  cat( "Sampling final MCMC chain...\n" )
  codaSamples = coda.samples( jagsModel , variable.names=parameters , 
                              n.iter=nIter , thin=thinSteps )
  # resulting codaSamples object has these indices: 
  #   codaSamples[[ chainIdx ]][ stepIdx , paramIdx ]
  if ( !is.null(saveName) ) {
    save( codaSamples , file=paste(saveName,"Mcmc.Rdata",sep="") )
  }
  return( codaSamples )
} # end function

#===============================================================================

smryMCMC = function(  codaSamples , compVal=0.5 , rope=NULL , 
                      compValDiff=0.0 , ropeDiff=NULL , saveName=NULL ) {
  mcmcMat = as.matrix(codaSamples,chains=TRUE)
  Ntheta = length(grep("theta",colnames(mcmcMat)))
  summaryInfo = NULL
  rowIdx = 0
  for ( tIdx in 1:Ntheta ) {
    parName = paste0("theta[",tIdx,"]")
    summaryInfo = rbind( summaryInfo , 
      summarizePost( mcmcMat[,parName] , compVal=compVal , ROPE=rope ) )
    rowIdx = rowIdx+1
    rownames(summaryInfo)[rowIdx] = parName
  }
  for ( t1Idx in 1:(Ntheta-1) ) {
    for ( t2Idx in (t1Idx+1):Ntheta ) {
      parName1 = paste0("theta[",t1Idx,"]")
      parName2 = paste0("theta[",t2Idx,"]")
      summaryInfo = rbind( summaryInfo , 
        summarizePost( mcmcMat[,parName1]-mcmcMat[,parName2] ,
                       compVal=compValDiff , ROPE=ropeDiff ) )
      rowIdx = rowIdx+1
      rownames(summaryInfo)[rowIdx] = paste0(parName1,"-",parName2)
    }
  }
  if ( !is.null(saveName) ) {
    write.csv( summaryInfo , file=paste(saveName,"SummaryInfo.csv",sep="") )
  }
  show( summaryInfo )
  return( summaryInfo )
}

#===============================================================================

plotMCMC = function( codaSamples , data , compVal=0.5 , rope=NULL , 
                     compValDiff=0.0 , ropeDiff=NULL , 
                     saveName=NULL , saveType="jpg" ) {
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # N.B.: This function expects the data to be a data frame, 
  # with one component named y being a vector of integer 0,1 values,
  # and one component named s being a factor of subject identifiers.
  y = data$y
  s = as.numeric(data$s) # converts character to consecutive integer levels
  # Now plot the posterior:
  mcmcMat = as.matrix(codaSamples,chains=TRUE)
  chainLength = NROW( mcmcMat )
  Ntheta = length(grep("theta",colnames(mcmcMat)))
  openGraph(width=2.5*Ntheta,height=2.0*Ntheta)
  par( mfrow=c(Ntheta,Ntheta) )
  for ( t1Idx in 1:(Ntheta) ) {
    for ( t2Idx in (1):Ntheta ) {
      parName1 = paste0("theta[",t1Idx,"]")
      parName2 = paste0("theta[",t2Idx,"]")
      if ( t1Idx > t2Idx) {  
        # plot.new() # empty plot, advance to next
        par( mar=c(3.5,3.5,1,1) , mgp=c(2.0,0.7,0) )
        nToPlot = 700
        ptIdx = round(seq(1,chainLength,length=nToPlot))
        plot ( mcmcMat[ptIdx,parName2] , mcmcMat[ptIdx,parName1] , cex.lab=1.75 ,
               xlab=parName2 , ylab=parName1 , col="skyblue" )
      } else if ( t1Idx == t2Idx ) {
        par( mar=c(3.5,1,1,1) , mgp=c(2.0,0.7,0) )
        postInfo = plotPost( mcmcMat[,parName1] , cex.lab = 1.75 , 
                             compVal=compVal , ROPE=rope , cex.main=1.5 ,
                             xlab=parName1 , main="" )
        includeRows = ( s == t1Idx ) # identify rows of this subject in data
        dataPropor = sum(y[includeRows])/sum(includeRows) 
        points( dataPropor , 0 , pch="+" , col="red" , cex=3 )
      } else if ( t1Idx < t2Idx ) {
        par( mar=c(3.5,1,1,1) , mgp=c(2.0,0.7,0) )
        postInfo = plotPost(mcmcMat[,parName1]-mcmcMat[,parName2] , cex.lab = 1.75 , 
                           compVal=compValDiff , ROPE=ropeDiff , cex.main=1.5 ,
                           xlab=paste0(parName1,"-",parName2) , main="" )
        includeRows1 = ( s == t1Idx ) # identify rows of this subject in data
        dataPropor1 = sum(y[includeRows1])/sum(includeRows1) 
        includeRows2 = ( s == t2Idx ) # identify rows of this subject in data
        dataPropor2 = sum(y[includeRows2])/sum(includeRows2) 
        points( dataPropor1-dataPropor2 , 0 , pch="+" , col="red" , cex=3 )
      }
    }
  }
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  if ( !is.null(saveName) ) {
    saveGraph( file=paste(saveName,"Post",sep=""), type=saveType)
  }
}

#===============================================================================
```

And this is code I used from the original source file:

```
# Load the data
myData = read.csv("dogcats_polliberal.csv") # myData is a data frame.

# Load the functions genMCMC, smryMCMC, and plotMCMC:
source("Jags-Ydich-XnomSsubj-MbernBeta.R")
# Generate the MCMC chain:
mcmcCoda = genMCMC( data = myData , numSavedSteps=50000 )
# Display diagnostics of chain, for specified parameter:
diagMCMC( mcmcCoda , parName="theta[1]" )
# Display numerical summary statistics of chain:
smryMCMC( mcmcCoda , compVal=NULL , compValDiff=0.0 )
# Display graphical posterior information:
plotMCMC( mcmcCoda , data=myData , compVal=NULL , compValDiff=0.0 )
```

The traceback error comes from the line in the original source file

```
jagsModel = jags.model( "TEMPmodel.txt" , data=dataList , inits=initsList , 
                          n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )
```

Can someone help me figure out why I get the error:

Also, I changed the s variable to numeric in the data file but I don't show it here. Keeping it as characters also gives another error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem *might* be this:

> The scripts that accompany DBDA2E have worked fine, "out of the box,"
> for years. But recently some scripts have had problems. Why? R has
> changed. With R 4.0.0, various functions such as read.csv() no longer
> automatically convert strings to factors. Some DBDA2E scripts assumed
> the results of those functions contained factors, but if you're now
> using R 4.0.0 (or more recent) those scripts will balk.
>
> So, what to do? Here's a temporary fix. When you open your R session,
> type in this global option: options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
>
> Unfortunately this option will eventually be deprecated. I'll have to
> modify every affected script and post updated versions. This will
> happen someday. I hope.
>
> Why did R change? You can read about it here:
>
> https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html

Text above was copied from this blog post, http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2020/09/fixing-new-problem-in-some-dbda2e.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and there are two possible solutions (both happened to me on different occasions):

1. dbern(0) is not defined.

Try rerunning with a (very very small) correction factor as outlined here:

```
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      y[i] ~ dbern( theta[s[i]]**+0.00000000001** )
    }
    for ( sIdx in 1:Nsubj ) {
      theta[sIdx] ~ dbeta( 2 , 2 ) # N.B.: 2,2 prior; change as appropriate.
    }
  }
  "
```

That should do the trick.

2. The other option is that you misspecified something in your list, data frame, input variables etc.

I am not quite sure that JAGS understands the part in bold correctly 1:Nsubj is 1:2, maybe try with names i in c("cat", "dog") or something like that.

```
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      y[i] ~ dbern( theta[s[i]] )
    }
    for ( **sIdx in 1:Nsubj** ) {
      theta[sIdx] ~ dbeta( 2 , 2 ) # N.B.: 2,2 prior; change as appropriate.
    }
  }
  "
```

The examples are great and make your model explicit but sometimes a little bit of context (i.e. what should your model do??) is helpful. Since this is a textbook example I doubt you're having issues with gross prior misspecification or something like that. But if you gave some context as to why you are using a numerical and a character column with ultimately the same structure that would be great!